# Problem when installing python Bringing-Old-Photos-Back-to-Life

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I decided to install https://github.com/microsoft/Bringing-Old-Photos-Back-to-Life
I never used Python in my life.
When doing

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I'm getting the errors as below.
Do you have any idea by what could it be caused and how could I solve it?

```
Collecting torch
  Downloading torch-1.4.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (753.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 753.4 MB 21 kB/s 
Collecting torchvision
  Downloading torchvision-0.5.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.0 MB 4.9 MB/s 
Collecting dlib
  Downloading dlib-19.22.0.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.4 MB 3.6 MB/s 
Collecting scikit-image
  Downloading scikit_image-0.14.5-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 25.5 MB 3.7 MB/s 
Collecting easydict
  Downloading easydict-1.9.tar.gz (6.4 kB)
Collecting PyYAML
  Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (574 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 574 kB 5.0 MB/s 
Collecting dominate>=2.3.1
  Downloading dominate-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting dill
  Downloading dill-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (81 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 81 kB 2.6 MB/s 
Collecting tensorboardX
  Downloading tensorboardX-2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 120 kB 4.4 MB/s 
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.2.3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 24.8 MB 4.0 MB/s 
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading opencv-python-4.3.0.38.tar.gz (88.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 88.0 MB 1.4 MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpD9TWJ0
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5ZWhEk/opencv-python
  Complete output (22 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_Yj_Kj/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_Yj_Kj/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_Yj_Kj/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 243, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_Yj_Kj/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 448, in <module>
      main()
    File "setup.py", line 99, in main
      % {"ext": re.escape(sysconfig.get_config_var("EXT_SUFFIX"))}
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 210, in escape
      s = list(pattern)
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpD9TWJ0 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `python-3.x` when you aren't using that version?

Comment: looking at the docker file in that github project suggests to me that this is a python3 project. You might try using pip3 rather than pip

Comment: In the [Requirement](https://github.com/microsoft/Bringing-Old-Photos-Back-to-Life#requirement) section of the GitHub link it says "Python>=3.6 is required to run the code." From what's in the error message, it looks like `python2.7` is being used.

Comment: error shows `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` so you use Python 2. You may have to run it with `pip3 install ...` or `python3 -m pip install ...`

Comment: Thanks for all comments. It was late night and I haven't catched this. :)